# Python: Add character to string an amount of times depending on an int

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, string-concatenation

Ok, I may have totally butchered the phrasing of this question since I can't quite word it but here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a CPU percentage displayed as characters in a string which show up on a display. If the cpu were at 52% I'd want the string to be CPU:[#####] 64% CPU:[######] but 77% CPU:[#######/] etc.

The only method I can thing off is having 20 if statements each with their own version of the string which shows dependant on the int percentage's value. I feel this would be a horrible way of doing it and wanted to know if there is a better way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the number of hashes to be the “tens digit” of the CPU percentage, this simple function will do it:

```
def cpu_usage_str(cpu_percentage):
    return 'CPU:[%s]' % ('#' * cpu_percentage / 10)

print cpu_usage_str(52)
print cpu_usage_str(64)
print cpu_usage_str(72)
```

(This assumes Python 2, with floor division. You’d need to tweak it slightly for Python 3.) We use the `*` operator to repeat the `'#'` string the appropriate number of times.

output:

```
CPU:[#####]
CPU:[######]
CPU:[#######]
```

Alternatively, if you’d like to round to the nearest ten (so 36% becomes `CPU:[####]`, say), then this will do the trick:

```
def alt_cpu_usage_str(cpu_percentage):
    return 'CPU:[%s]' % ('#' * int(round(cpu_percentage / 10.0)))
```

First we divide by `10.0` to get a float between `0.0` and `10.0`. Then `round` takes us to the nearest whole number. This is represented by a float, so we convert it to an int and then repeat the string as before.

---

If we want a backslash to indicate whether we're under/over 5, then we need to consider `cpu_percentage % 10` (the `%` is the modulo operator). Here's a function which does it:

```
def with_slashes_cpu_usage_str(cpu_percentage):
    hashes_str = '#' * int(round(cpu_percentage / 10))
    slash_str  = '/' * (cpu_percentage % 10 >= 5)
    return 'CPU:[{hash}{slash}]'.format(hash=hashes_str, slash=slash_str)
```

We construct the hash and slash strings separately. The bool `cpu_percentage % 10 >= 5` is coerced to 0 or 1, which gives us the slash, or not, depending on whether or not we're in the upper half of that 10.

If you want [ ]5% not to print that trailing slash, then change to a strict inequality.

Comment: Thanks! this is almost perfect. I am also trying to make the '/'s equal fives to allow for a better degree of accuracy. How would I make it able to work out whether the last one is <= 5% to get the / at the end for say 77?

Comment: Just to note: `//` is available for integer division in both 2.x and 3.x

Comment: Ok, so right now that outputs 15% as if it were 25%. Is there a way  to set it so it just changes the last hash for a / instead of putting it on the end?

Comment: @RichieaaronMorris: Oops. Mixing floats and ints by accident. Fixed in edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat a string using `*`, e.g. `'#'*5` gives `'#####'`

```
print "CPU:[%s]"%('#'*(percentage/10))
```